# A duck for a well-known bowler (5): How to solve it?

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

The following is a cryptic clue<sup>1</sup>:

> A duck for a well-known bowler (5)

I know that the answer is:

> Drake

While I understand that:

> a male duck is called a "*drake*"

How does it relate to the cryptic clue?

---

<sub>1 The source for this cryptic clue is the *Irish Independent* cryptic crossword from 06/05/2020, found [here](https://www.crosswordassistant.com/publication/irish-independent-crossword-solutions/irish-independent-cryptic-6-may-2020-6phdvvbu) (this link contains a spoiler) thanks to @TripeHound's answer</sub>

Comment: Please provide the source of this cryptic clue.

Comment: This guy? (we don't do that sport in my country, so no idea about him being well-known) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Drake#Cricket_career

Answer (score 17):

> If the origin of the clue is an English crossword<sup>**1**</sup> (as opposed to just an *English language* crossword), then I believe that the clue is referring to [Sir Francis Drake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Drake) (Wikipedia). He was an Elizabethan explorer who circumnavigated the world and, of relevance to the clue:

> > The most famous (but probably apocryphal) anecdote about Drake relates that, prior to the battle, **he was playing a game of bowls on Plymouth Hoe**. On being warned of the approach of the Spanish fleet, Drake is said to have remarked that there was plenty of time to finish the game and still beat the Spaniards.

> Thus both "*A [male] duck*" and "*a well-known bowler*" lead to "*Drake*".

> <sup>**1**</sup> According to the [Crossword Assistant](https://www.crosswordassistant.com/clue/a-duck-for-a-well-known-bowler-wd2e9893) site, this clue occurred in the *Irish Independent*, 6 May 2020 (and the answer was "Drake"). While that's neither an English, nor even a British newspaper, I strongly suspect they will have intended the Sir Francis Drake allusion.